# How Can I Fix This TypeError

Tags: python

```
def file_name(strings):
    file_name = input('Enter file name you want to save it: ')
file = open(file_name, 'wt')
file.write(strings)
file.close()
```

Above is my code that keeps getting the error below. I am trying to save text into a new file.

```
file = open(file_name, 'wt')
    TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not function
```

Comment: Please read a tutorial about functions in Python. This is not how they work.

Comment: You function name and the variable defined inside the function has the same name "file_name". Please provide different names and check whether it works.

Answer (score 3):

You have a function called `file_name`.  The variable inside that function is local to the function and won't be seen outside.  I think you misunderstand what functions are for.

Having taken a second look, however, I think you expected all of those lines to be PART of the function, and you have the indentation wrong.  Perhaps you intended this:

```
def file_name(strings):
    file_name = input('Enter file name you want to save it: ')
    file = open(file_name, 'wt')
    file.write(strings)
    file.close()
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To define a function, you should indent all the code of the function, not only the first line.
It should become this:

```py
def file_name(strings):
    file_name = input('Enter file name you want to save it: ')
    file = open(file_name, 'wt')
    file.write(strings)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you have a function named "file_name" and the function does not return anything. To fix your issue, you need to make two edits.

First, the function needs to return the input (and doesn't need the strings keyword):

```
def file_name():
    return input('Enter file name you want to save it: ')
```

Second, the function needs to be called, not referenced as an object, so add brackets to it:

```
file = open(file_name(), 'wt')
```